# Chrome and Edge blocks printing but on firefox it works

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing, office365, microsoft-edge

While I am in the browser page, https://mycompany.com/office365-editor/some-file-id, where I can edit and view some office document, I want to also use the printing functionality. So I click on print and see a pop up : [image: yourFileIsReadyToPrintPopUp] but after I click on "Open PDF" a new tab in the browser opens with following error message:

> ffc-word-edit.officeapps.live.com ist gesperrt
> Diese Seite wurde von Chrome blockiert
> ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

I only experience this behavior on Chrome and Edge. On Firebox or Safari it just works.

My guess it has something to do with the chrome ad blocker.

When I look at the network tab and find the request
https://ffc-word-edit.officeapps.live.com/we/WordViewer/request.pdf?sometokens
and copy it manually in another tab, I see a pdf ready to print where I can choose the printer as I expected to be in the first place.

Comment: The issue might be related with extensions installed in Chrome and Edge. Will the issue disappear if you disable all extensions in Chrome and Edge? You can also try to load and print the page in Incognito Mode to see if it works.

Comment: No, nothing changes when i disable all extensions in Chrome and Edge. Also Incognito Mode doesn't help at all

Comment: Which version of Chrome and Edge do you use? I found a [similar thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/security-dev/c/Abvu9qL-nzk) and someone says it still has issue in latest Chrome. You can check if you encounter the same sandbox CSP issue. If yes, I think you need to raise a new issue on [chromium website](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).

Comment: Edge : Version 108.0.1462.76 (Offizielles Build) (64-Bit)
Chrome: Version 108.0.5359.125 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit)

I think, will raise an issue on the chromium website. Thank you

Comment: That's the latest version. But when I test in o365, I can open PDF from word file successfully in Edge and Chrome. So it might still have something to do with your environment settings. You can also check if you have installed some kind of blocking software, it will also cause the issue. Besides, try to check you don't set Tracking prevention to Strict in *edge://settings/privacy*.